# "Leave This Page" button. Prevent from loading

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I had a website come up that said my system was locked and I had to pay money to get it unlocked.  Additionally, there was a window with "Leave This Page" button and "Stay On This Page" button. Clicking the first button did nothing...I couldn't even exit Chrome.  How do I prohibit all websites with this despicable behavior from loading?  Or, better yet, how do I destroy their entire existence?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a HTML5 features asking you if you want to leave the page. This behavior is very strange and would like to see the cause of the problem. Are you able to provide some information like images or even the link witch I could take a look at to see for myself to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour for many sites which may want you to make sure that you do not leave while filling a form or similar ([askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) itself uses it). In all cases I've personally encountered, I could exit with the "Leave this page" button. Are you sure that this is not a coincidence or related to another problem or program?